# Setting up our Rasa/NLU container, error?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rasa-nlu

I have this file Dockerfile.nlu

```
FROM chatbot/spacy:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY nlu ./agent_nlu
RUN python –m rasa_nlu.train --config agent_nlu/config.yml --data agent_nlu/data/ --path agent_nlu/agent --fixed_model_name default
```

and I get the error below:

```
]$ sudo docker build -t nlu:latest -f docker/Dockerfile.nlu .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  9.216kB
Step 1/4 : FROM chatbot/spacy:latest
 ---> 496dc6a38abb
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7f02012c8452
Step 3/4 : COPY nlu ./agent_nlu
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder363868051/nlu: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like Docker can find the `nlu` directory. Are you sure it exists? Are you sure that you are executing the command from the correct directory?

But you also aren't installing Rasa at all or any of it's requirements. Is there a reason you aren't using the pre-built Rasa images? available [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/rasa/rasa_nlu) with docs [here](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/0.13.8/docker/#running-in-docker).

Here is a fully functional Docker file pulled from their [repo](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/tree/master/docker).

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

ENV RASA_NLU_DOCKER="YES" \
    RASA_NLU_HOME=/app \
    RASA_NLU_PYTHON_PACKAGES=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages

# Run updates, install basics and cleanup
# - build-essential: Compile specific dependencies
# - git-core: Checkout git repos
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential git-core openssl libssl-dev libffi6 libffi-dev curl  \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

WORKDIR ${RASA_NLU_HOME}

COPY . ${RASA_NLU_HOME}

# use bash always
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

RUN pip install -r alt_requirements/requirements_spacy_sklearn.txt

RUN pip install -e .

RUN pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_md-2.0.0/en_core_web_md-2.0.0.tar.gz --no-cache-dir > /dev/null \
    && python -m spacy link en_core_web_md en \
    && pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/de_core_news_sm-2.0.0/de_core_news_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz --no-cache-dir > /dev/null \
    && python -m spacy link de_core_news_sm de

COPY sample_configs/config_spacy.yml ${RASA_NLU_HOME}/config.yml

VOLUME ["/app/projects", "/app/logs", "/app/data"]

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["start", "-c", "config.yml", "--path", "/app/projects"]
```